# A qué se debe mi NullPointerException en mi prueba?

Tags: java, junit

Estoy realizando una prueba unitaria pero al momento de ejecutarla me salta el siguiente mensaje:

> java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   tcs.shieldtecs.test.TestCryptoHsm.testCryptoFileXML_Ok(TestCryptoHsm.java:84)

Dentro de mi prueba tengo el siguiente código:

```
  @org.junit.Test
    public void test()
    {     

        String username="nombre";
        String llave = userDAO.findOneByCryptoSynKey(username); //linea 84
        Key key = keyDAO.findOneByName(llave);
        DataWSHsmInput dataInput = new DataWSHsmInput();
```

Comment: puedes indicar cual es la línea 84 de tu código? ahí dice que está el error

Comment: mira https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-soluci%C3%B3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados

Comment: Tiene pinta de que userDAO es null